# trying to do where not in

Tags: mysql, database

```
select purchase_orders.purchase_order_id, order_date, department_id
from purchase_orders
join purchase_order_lines
    on purchase_orders.purchase_order_id = purchase_order_lines.purchase_order_id
where not exists (select purchase_orders.purchase_order_id = purchase_order_lines.purchase_order_id);
```

I am trying to make sure that it only shows purchase orders that are not part of a purchase order line.  I keep getting error and I am not sure how to make it work.  Any help would be great.

Comment: You're looking for `LEFT JOIN`, and `WHERE purchase_order_lines.purchase_order_id IS NULL`; `EXISTS` typically expects a normal query.

Comment: i need to use exist since this is a project where the prof demands it

Comment: Your inner select (the one used on not exists condition) has no sense, you have to make it in the form `select <columns> from <table> where <condition>`

Comment: @Caleb you do not need the join at all then, just select from the second table in the exists subquery.